# Force cypress to type on aria-hidden input

Tags: cypress, hidden

I am new to cypress but it seems to be love at first sight although I am already facing some issues after updating my browser. I am trying to create a test to write a google doc, obviously the user needs to be signed in to be able to do so. So I've been looking to sign in through the API which doesnt seem to be possible cause you need to have a google workspace login which I dont and cant get cause I am not at uni nor I am using my work email. So I decided to do the sign in "manually" google though looks to be very much on top with their security system, the password input element is hidden, in particular I can see aria-hidden = true. I tried in any way, such as type ({force:true}), also tried to access the div on top of it but nothing. Has anyone got the same issue before with google logging in?

Answer (score 0):

I have the seem problem. Can you resolved it?

Maybe you can use cy.get('element').should('exist')
and then
cy.get('element').should('contain', 'email')

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I think what @Werokk tries to say is that some sites/frameworks etc. create components like selects, radio button groups,  even buttons etc. from scratch instead of using or styling the DOM equivalents. Yet, for various reasons, they still utilize the respective standard DOM input elements under the hood. Those are however hidden either by giving them a dimension of 0x0, absolutely positioning the custom components on top of them or simply by hiding them using CSS. Ant-Design is one such framework and you can refer to their select or radio button group components to see an instance of the mentioned pattern.

The problem is that the relevant aria attributes (role, aria-label etc.) are set on those hidden/covered elements, not the custom component. Trying to set the role on the Ant-Design components manually, even results in typescript errors as the role attribute is neither defined by the Antd Props nor passed along if used anyway.

Therefore using Cypress in conjunction with a library like `testing-library` which [promotes using aria roles](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about/#priority) to query such elements (lest we end up having a bunch of brittle white-box tests that break with every change to the underlying DOM structure) fails miserably as those elements are found but can't be interacted with.

I am struggling with the same problem but the solution is not to force Cypress to simulate a click on the element but to fix the issue upstream for example by having the library set the aria role and attributes on the elements that Cypress would query and interact with. That's because the actual user couldn't possibly interact with those elements either and Cypress tries to emulate what a user would do manually.

Regarding the example above with the Google application, I suspect that there is a similar pattern involved i. e. the login input field is a a custom component but uses the actual standard input elements under the hood. In that case I would modify the Cypress query as to interact with the custom component instead. Almost always those elements can be interacted with using the Cypress API if you can interact with them manually (and evidently you can, otherwise you wouldn't have been able to log in).